# useEffect tries to read property of object before the state was updated in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, setstate, use-state

I am cascading data to my components with `createContext()` in React. In this I have an API call, where I'm fetching two different arrays of objects, mapping over them, and creating a final set of data like:

```
const [organizationData, setOrganizationData] = useState([
    {
        id: "",
        orgName: "",
        street: "",
        city: ""
    }
])

const organizationFunction = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await axios
        .get(
            API_URL + `organizations/${someUniqueId}`
        )
        .then(res => {
            const masterData = res.data.master
            const contactData = res.data.contact
            const combinedData = masterData.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, contactData[i]))
            setOrganizationData(combinedData)
        })
        setOrgLoading(true)
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
    }
}
```

Then I send the data to children

```
<AuthContext.Provider organizationData={organizationData}>
    {children}
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Now, when I try to access this data from one of the children, specifically to populate the inputs of a form with the data from the database, with the help of useEffect when the component is mount, it crashes because in the beginning `organizationData` is undefined, just the empty object I have defined upfront, so it tries to read `organizationData.orgName` and breaks with `Cannot read property 'orgName' of undefined`.

If I `console.log(organizationData)` in the Context component, the output is

```
[{…}]
0: {id: "", orgName: "", street: "", city: ""}

(1) [{…}]
0: {id: 12, orgName: "MyOrganization", street: "Skalitzerstr. 31", city: "Berlin"}
```

So the first output is empty and then the state updates.

I have tried to short circuit when adding data to my form in my child component but that is not working, it still crashes with `Cannot read property 'orgName' of undefined`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFillingData({
      ...fillingData,
      orgName: organizationData.orgName || "",
      ...
  })
}
```

Any idea what exactly is wrong here, and how can I avoid exporting `organizationData` before the state was updated and the data/object created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `organizationData` in dependency array of useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(organizationData){
    setFillingData({
      ...fillingData,
      orgName: organizationData.orgName || "",
      ...
   })
  }
}, [organizationData])
```